# Store numeric value as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that redirects the user to the admin of a page and adds `?delete=` with a number at the end, for example: `?delete=1`.

On the page that it redirects to, I want jQuery to find the id with the numeric value, in this case 1, and then execute a function.

I thought it'd be best to store the numeric value as a variable, because it'd be easier to execute, but I don't know how to do that.

The number is different so I can't just add that number.

I wanted to do:

```
var exampleid = 1; (the end number on the URL)

$('body').find('#' + example).addClass('selected');
```

I know that I could use `window.location.pathname`, but it'll store `?delete=` as well as the number when I only need the numeric value.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know they were called query string values. Can I get the numeric value from a query string?

Comment: Yes...? Use `parseInt()` if you need to.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest setting `id` attributes as numbers (although it's allowed). At least make them something like `id="delete2"` and then find it with `.find("#delete" + exampleid)`. Just a design suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;

var exampleid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

$('body').find('#' + exampleid).addClass('selected');
```

---

or if you always want to get the last character in your url, just do:

```
var exampleid = url.slice(-1);
```

---

If you want to get the last number, you need to use regex:

```
var exampleid = parseInt(url.match(/\d+$/), 10);
```

Comment: This will only work under very specific circumstances...

Comment: What's the `1` for? The 1 in my example was just an example, it'll be different everytime.

Comment: @user2203362 that statement is to get the next character of your url after the last occurence of `=`

Comment: Hmm..but your slice wont work if numbers are in more than one digit like `10, 100, 1000` etc `.substr()` is quite better.

Comment: @Jai I said character :)

Comment: @user2203362 I'd suggest using the last example in this answer - the Regex one. It allow for any number of digits at the end of your URL...so it will get `103` from `?delete=103`, when the first two examples will not. I guess it's up to you. If it will only ever be one digit, stick to `slice` then.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll use Regex then. Thank you!